# why isn't mate-optimus applet showing?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus, gnome-tweak-tool

Im using Ubuntu 19.10. and Nvidia driver 435. I tried installing the [mate-optimus](https://github.com/ubuntu-mate/mate-optimus) applet for easy use of Nvidia's offloading feature.

I installed it by using `sudo apt install mate-optimus`. I got the gnome-tweaks settings for applets activated. I managed to configure the X server and having "NVIDIA-G0" show up, as explained by nvidia [here](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/435.21/README/primerenderoffload.html). But until now the Applet doesn't show up. What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

After I de- an reactivated Gnome extensions and rebootet, the applet did finally show up! But strangely just the Intel-mode or the Nvidia-mode shows and not the On-Demand mode:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

After I manually switched on the On-Demand Mode in the Nvidia settings and rebooted, the applet now does show this option! However, if Im in either Intel or Nvidia mode, then the On-Demand option doesn't show upon reboot - but thats fine, now I know how to let it appear,